# Npgsql BeginTextImport try import from file (not from STDIN)

Tags: npgsql

I try import data to postgresql table from file via npgsql BeginTextImport
This is my code:

```
public Object Copy(String sSchemaAndTableName, String sFilePath, Boolean bIsImport)
    {
        Boolean bRet = true;

        Object oResult = new Object();
        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(sConnectionString);
        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();            

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            NpgsqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();

            if (File.Exists(sFilePath))
            {
                try
                {
                    if (bIsImport)
                    {
                        conn.BeginTextImport("COPY " + sSchemaAndTableName + " FROM '" + sFilePath + "';");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        conn.BeginTextExport("COPY " + sSchemaAndTableName + " TO '" + sFilePath + "';");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    bRet = false;
                    transaction.Rollback();

                    throw e;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (bRet)
                    {
                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Plik nie istnieje: " + sFilePath);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                                
            MW.Core.Common.Objects.Exceptions.Items.Add(ex);
            oResult = null;
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();

            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }

        return oResult;
    }
```

when i run this i get errors - look at the screen's:

[when i use myapp directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2c9N.png)

[when i use postresql server data directory - this works when i use pgadmin but from my app via npgsql not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WTNR.png)

It is possible to do?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Can I suggest you summarise the error messages in your post so that people can see them without clicking on the image links (and find them later in searches.) Images don't have to go, but having the error message text will help you get more responses.

Comment: Hi, ok i remember @wwkudu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL's "COPY from a file" feature doesn't do what you probably thinks it does; it doesn't import data from a file on the *client* side (where Npgsql is running), but rather from a file on the *server* side (where PostgreSQL is running). In other words, you can put a file on your PostgreSQL server and tell PostgreSQL to import it.

If you want to import a file on the client machine, you need to open it in C#, read from it and write into the TextWriter that BeginTextImport returns.

Comment: Thank's @Shay Rojansky, you're right, i found usefull example here [link](https://github.com/Emill/Npgsql/blob/master/test/Npgsql.Tests/CopyTests.cs) for the one who will read this.

Answer (score 2):

Now my code works great, (thank you @Shay Rojansky one more time)

```
public Boolean CopyFrom(String sDestinationSchemaAndTableName, String sFromFilePath)
    {
        Boolean bRet = true;

        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(sConnectionString);
        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();            

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            NpgsqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();

            if (File.Exists(sFromFilePath))
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var writer = conn.BeginTextImport("COPY " + sDestinationSchemaAndTableName + " FROM STDIN"))
                    {
                        foreach (String sLine in File.ReadAllLines(sFromFilePath))
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(sLine);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    bRet = false;
                    transaction.Rollback();

                    throw e;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (bRet)
                    {
                        transaction.Commit();
                    }

                    transaction.Dispose();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MW.Core.Common.Objects.Exceptions.Items.Add(new Exception("Plik nie istnieje: " + sFromFilePath));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                                
            MW.Core.Common.Objects.Exceptions.Items.Add(ex);
            bRet = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();

            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }

        return bRet;
    }
```