# Defensive parameter for COPY query with Npgsql?

Tags: .net, security, sql-injection, npgsql

I would like to compose a [NpgsqlConnection.BeginTextExport()](http://www.npgsql.org/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.html) query specifying the table to be exported as a parameter. The [naive way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33612897/npgsql-begintextimport-try-import-from-file-not-from-stdin) to do this is:

```
using (var reader = conn.BeginTextExport("COPY " + myTable + " TO STDOUT"))
{
   Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
}
```

But I don't like it because of the obvious SQL injection pattern. I can think of many somewhat complicated options to sanitize the `myTable` field, but I am wondering if what is the canonical pattern here. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1677.

The gist of the answer is that Npgsql simply forwards parameters to PostgreSQL (rather than doing substitution client-side), and PostgreSQL doesn't support parameters in table names. See the github answer for some rationale for this.